# Query to Move Into Separate Column

Tags: mysql

Currently i'm stuck for searching best query to make a resume of attendance log database.

Here is the current layout of 'absen' table:

```
id|employee_id|          log        |status
1 | 1         | 2019-03-27 07:58:32 |  in
2 | 1         | 2019-03-27 07:58:38 |  in
3 | 1         | 2019-03-27 17:12:34 |  out
4 | 2         | 2019-03-26 07:45:12 |  in
5 | 2         | 2019-03-26 18:22:54 |  out
6 | 1         | 2019-03-28 07:45:38 |  in
7 | 1         | 2019-03-28 17:10:55 |  out
8 | 2         | 2019-03-27 07:59:02 |  in
9 | 2         | 2019-03-27 18:35:16 |  out
```

And here is the goal

```
employee_id|          in         |        out
    2      | 2019-03-26 07:45:12 | 2019-03-26 18:22:54
    1      | 2019-03-27 07:58:32 | 2019-03-27 17:12:34
    2      | 2019-03-27 07:59:02 | 2019-03-27 18:35:16
    1      | 2019-03-28 07:45:38 | 2019-03-28 17:10:55
```

(ORDER BY in ASC)

I already try this query:

```
SELECT
    dateng.e_idIN AS "PIN",
    MASUK,
    PULANG
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MIN(log) AS "MASUK",
        employee_id AS e_idIN
    FROM
        absen
    WHERE
        status = "in"
    GROUP BY
        log
) dateng
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        MAX(log) AS "PULANG",
        employee_id AS e_idOUT
    FROM
        absen
    WHERE
        status = "out"
    GROUP BY
        log
) pergi
ON
    dateng.e_idIN = pergi.e_idOUT
```

but the result is not as expected

```
PIN |         MASUK       |         PULANG
2   | 2019-03-26 07:45:12 | 2019-03-27 18:35:16
2   | 2019-03-26 07:45:12 | 2019-03-26 18:22:54
1   | 2019-03-27 07:58:32 | 2019-03-28 17:10:55
1   | 2019-03-27 07:58:32 | 2019-03-27 17:12:34
1   | 2019-03-27 07:58:38 | 2019-03-28 17:10:55
1   | 2019-03-27 07:58:38 | 2019-03-27 17:12:34
2   | 2019-03-27 07:59:02 | 2019-03-27 18:35:16
2   | 2019-03-27 07:59:02 | 2019-03-26 18:22:54
1   | 2019-03-28 07:45:38 | 2019-03-28 17:10:55
1   | 2019-03-28 07:45:38 | 2019-03-27 17:12:34
```

Any clue for this task?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, i will go through your links

Comment: ___but the result is not as expected___ Not a hepful description of your issue! Please show error messages or at least the result (if you get one)

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, i have updated my question by adding the "unexpected" result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this will work:

```
select t.employee_id, min(t.login) login, t.logout  
from (
  select a.employee_id, a.log login, 
  (select min(log) from absen 
   where status = 'out' and employee_id = a.employee_id and log > a.log) logout
  from absen a
  where a.status = 'in'
) t
group by t.employee_id, t.logout  
order by t.login, t.logout
```

Comment: Hi @forpas, I tried your query and have an error on the first line. Changed min(t.log)  into  min(t.in) and the query can be run. However, there are flaws on the query result, which show in and out at wrong time for a row

Comment: I edited, changed the names from in and out which are reserved words to login logout. Try again and check if this was the problem.

Comment: AWESOME! It works now! It will take some time for me to digest your query, meanwhile I will kudos this as the answer...